# jquery ui dialog position

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

How can i set the position of jquery ui dialog. when i click finish in my form the position of the dialog is at the top of the page..

here's how i call dialog:

```
            <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
                <h1>Transaction successful!</h1>
                <br />

                <h3>Thank you.</h3>
            </div>

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showmessage", "jQuery('#dialog').dialog({ dialogClass: 'no-close',  title: 'Registration Successful', autoOpen: true,  height: 300, width: 600, modal: true, draggable: true, resizable: false, buttons: { Ok: function () { window.location.replace('Login.aspx'); } } }); ", true);
```

please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional parameter `POSITION` for this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button } });
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position for more information.

Edit example based on the existing code:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType()
 , "showmessage"
 , "jQuery('#dialog').dialog({ 
   dialogClass: 'no-close'
   ,  title: 'Registration Successful'
   , autoOpen: true
   ,  height: 300
   , width: 600
   , modal: true
   , draggable: true
   , resizable: false
   , position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button } //as per the jqueryUI example will need to customize for your needs.
   , buttons: { Ok: function () { window.location.replace('Login.aspx'); } } }); ", true);
```

Comment: how can i call this in my code behind..i didn't make a jquery function for the dialog instead i called it in my code behind...

Comment: question...how will i set my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button? sorry haven't used this before..
i tried doing like this:
position: { my: 'left', at: 'left', of: button }
when i run my code, it doesnt show the dialog..